# R 4.3.1 and tidyverse crashes

Tags: r, dplyr, segmentation-fault, tidyverse

I have a dplyr/tidyverse heavy application to maintain which seems to struggle in R 4.3.1.

In R 4.3.1 I observed the following:

Running the script in Rscript or emacs-ess under R 4.3.1 yields changes in variable types (loop counter changing to list inside loops, subsequent error), loss of previously sourced function(i.e. "could not find function xzy", subsequent error), and also entire R crashes with memory allocation error messages.

I have installed R 4.1.2 in a Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine and the same script runs without issues.

What I have done so far:

I have uninstalled and re-installed the entire R package, version 4.3.1, including recompilation of all packages from source. The issues remain.

I have compared the versions of packages being used under R 4.1.2 and R 4.3.1 via sessionInfo(), checking "loadedOnly" and "otherPKGS". All 52 packages have the same version except 4: lattice, grid, codetools, and compiler.

Since I haven't seen any problems with R 4.3.1 except this particular script my current guess is an incompatibility of dplyr/tidyverse and R 4.3.1. This guess is because this script is the only of my scripts which uses tidyverse.

Any idea on how to narrow where the problem is in R 4.3.1. much appreciated.

OS: Linux
Kernel: 6.4.9.
gcc version: 13.2.1

Comment: this sounds like potentiallly something you should post as an Issue on the dplyr or tidyverse Github page. Also just as a sidenote, it's great to see a question asker so thoroughly research and investigate things for themselves before posting (+1) A+ question

Comment: dplyr passes the CRAN checks. It is not incompatible with r-release. Nobody should be using code that depends on the tidyverse package in production. That is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I disagree with @Mark, you should not post this as an issue on their github repo. It's nice that you have investigated a lot but how could someone find a solution without a reproducible example for this? Only make a github issue once you have found the source of this and if it appears it's because of one of the `tidyverse` packages

Comment: "Any idea on how to narrow where the problem is in R 4.3.1" -> if the problem is likely caused by a single script then break this script piece by piece to find what is crashing the session

Comment: obviously @bretauv I'm not, nor was I ever suggesting OP posts their question verbatim on Github, that's ridiculous

Comment: Well your comment could be read like that, glad we agree on this ;)

Comment: Could you add a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Please add your current OS (is it still Ubuntu 22.04 virtual?)  under which this is happening. Further,  and this is important: some packages may well require updating to be compatible with changes in the core of 4.3.1 .  But absolutely do put a pile of breakpoints into your code and see what call is causing the crash. Then backtrack from there to see if any data object is no longer the class, or size, or containing values that it does under your older setup.